# Django ignores APPEND_SLASHES

Tags: django, firefox

I've set the `APPEND_SLASHES` directive to `False` in my `settings.py` file and yet Django carries on to redirect **some** (but not all) requests which is **incredibly annoying**. What could be causing this issue?

Basically, if I make a request without the slash, it will return the correct response body, but with a redirect (301), redirecting it to the same URL but with a slash at the end **which will not match because it shouldn't end in a slash**.

Is there a fix for that or do I just need to strip the slash redirection code from `CommonMiddleware`?

**Edit:** `CommonMiddleware` is not the culprit. The URL reaches it with a slash at the end.

**Edit2:** Only happens in Firefox. *What the hell?* Firebug registers **two** HTTP requests, one of which is a redirect. Only **one** request actually hits the server, and it's the one with the slash at the end. The 301 appears out of nowhere and isn't even sent (Wireshark doesn't register it).

Comment: It's  APPEND_SLASH not APPEND_SLASHES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

301 are permament redirects. So if you have had this option set to true before firefox will still remember this permament redirect and go to page with slash appended. Try to clear firefoxes caches and offline contents.